# Showing that if $X$ is left-invariant and $\varphi(\sigma)=\sigma^{-1},$ then $d\varphi(X)$ is right-invariant.

Tags: lie-groups, vector-fields

> If $\varphi: G \rightarrow G$ is a diffeomorphism defined by
> $\varphi(\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}$ and $X$ is a left-invariant vector field
> on $G$, then $d\varphi(X)$ is the right-invariant vector field whose
> value at $e$ is $-X(e)$.

This question is from F. Warner's Manifolds, Chapter 3, Problem 16, and was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522070/x-left-invariant-rightarrow-d-phi-x-right-invariant). I am trying to understand the solution presented in that answer, however.

According to the definition in the book, we are to show that
$$dr_\sigma \circ d\phi(X) = d\phi(X)\circ r_\sigma.$$
On the other hand, it suffices to show that
$$dr_{\sigma}(d\phi(X))=d\phi(X)$$
according to that answer. Why can we remove the $r_\sigma$ from the RHS? Moreover, why is it true that
$$d\phi(X)=d(\phi\circ l_{\sigma})(X)$$
as claimed in the answer?

Many thanks — I have already spent too long on this problem!